# How can I render 3D objects from a list of triangular coordinates?

Tags: file-format, 3d

I tried asking this question on StackOverflow with slightly different phrasing. It wasn't answered and we determined that it was off-topic. It wasn't moved, so I'm asking here.

I have a file (created by an unknown program) that seems to contain coordinates for a triangle mesh in 3D space. The first few lines look like this:

```
-0.000000,2.758621,12.413793 0.798542,2.443666,15.312572 2.584137,2.443666,12.413793
-0.000000,-18.758621,12.413793 2.090611,-18.443666,10.622249 2.090610,-18.443666,14.205337
-0.000000,2.758621,12.413793 2.584137,2.443666,12.413793 0.798542,2.443666,9.515014
-0.000000,2.758621,12.413793 0.798542,2.443666,9.515014 -2.090611,2.443666,10.622249
```

The rest of the file (over 47 kB) follows this pattern.

I want to be able to see the model represented by this data. Is there an easy way to make a program, like Meshlab, recognize this as a 3D object and render it? Another way to say it is that I want to convert this raw data to a valid format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a text editor or some scripting you could transform your text file to a [POV-Ray](http://povray.org/) scene description using the `mesh` object.

```
mesh {
  triangle {
    <x1,y1,z1>, <x2,y2,z2>, <x3,y3,z3>
    <x1,y1,z1>, <x2,y2,z2>, <x3,y3,z3>
    <x1,y1,z1>, <x2,y2,z2>, <x3,y3,z3>
    ...
    texture { ... }
  }
}
```

Comment: It took a while, but I wrote a script to transform my file into the format shown by you and the POV-Ray documentation, then rendered it. Unfortunately it was just a pile of primitive shapes rather than something interesting that I made.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a "point cloud" and most 3D CAD or modeling systems can import them.

What you do next it up to you... Do you want to turn that cloud into a wireframe mesh?  Then you'll need to tell the software which points need to be connected to which other points.

Many solid modeling systems  (Pro/e, etc) also provide the ability to "drape a surface" over a point cloud (assuming that the points approximate a surface).

Once you've upgraded you point cloud to a wireframe, surface, or solid, you should be able to export in any number of 3D formats (iges, 3ds,stl, vrml, and so on)

Example: here's a google sketchup plugin that does something like this : http://rhin.crai.archi.fr/rld/plugin_details.php?id=777

Comment: Look closer: there are groups of three separated by commas, and three of those separated by spaces on each line. Ergo, triangles, not a cloud of unassociated points.

Comment: Ahhh.... On my screen (iphone) each trio of numbers is on its own line.  You may want to include that description in the question for other mobile users.